# IntelliJ Idea IDE: Abnormal build process termination. How to fix that?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I guess that's because of Cyrillic symbols in paths which IDE cannot digest correctly during build process, but I cannot just rename this folder in Windows 10.
Tried to make a junction using MKLINK \J, but it didn't help..
I suppose the Cyrillic symbols in Windows username made the IDE throw

```
java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <?> at index 9: C:/Users/????/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IdeaIC2022.1/log/build-log\build-log-jul.properties
```

but I couldn't fix it. Reinstalling IDE didn't bring any luck

```
Abnormal build process termination: 
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin\java.exe" -Xmx700m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs=\"\" -Dcompile.parallel=false -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true -Daether.connector.resumeDownloads=false -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=-4495793791689339547 -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.language=ru -Duser.country=RU -Didea.paths.selector=IdeaIC2022.1 "-Didea.home.path=C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1" -Didea.config.path=C:/Users/Егор/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2022.1 -Didea.plugins.path=C:/Users/Егор/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2022.1/plugins -Djps.log.dir=C:/Users/Егор/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IdeaIC2022.1/log/build-log "-Djps.fallback.jdk.home=C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1/jbr" -Djps.fallback.jdk.version=11.0.14.1 -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Djps.backward.ref.index.builder=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation.js=true -Dkotlin.daemon.enabled -Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path=\"C:\Users\A946~1\AppData\Local\Temp\kotlin-idea-11640337927034352620-is-running\" "-Djps.kotlin.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc" -Dtmh.instrument.annotations=true -Dtmh.generate.line.numbers=true -classpath "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_171/lib/tools.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders-6.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1/plugins/java/lib/jps-javac-extension.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1/lib/util.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1/lib/util_rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1/lib/annotations.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1/lib/3rd-party-rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1/lib/jna.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1/lib/lz4-java.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1/lib/protobuf.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1/lib/jps-model.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1/plugins/java/lib/javac2.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1/lib/forms_rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1/plugins/java/lib/aether-dependency-resolver.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1/lib/idea_rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1/plugins/Kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-common.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-common.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1/plugins/space/lib/space-java-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1/plugins/uiDesigner/lib/jps/java-guiForms-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1/plugins/IntelliLang/lib/java-langInjection-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-constants-rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1/plugins/ant/lib/ant-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1/plugins/gradle-java/lib/gradle-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1/plugins/devkit/lib/devkit-jps.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 64816 91edec9e-f56d-4682-b5b8-47178d281b2b C:/Users/Егор/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IdeaIC2022.1/compile-server
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:43)
Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <?> at index 9: C:/Users/????/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IdeaIC2022.1/log/build-log\build-log-jul.properties
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.LogSetup.initLoggers(LogSetup.java:31)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain.<clinit>(BuildMain.java:47)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Is ???? what is actually printed or have you anonymized your username?

Comment: @thorbjørn-ravn-andersen Hello! No, it's the exact output which I copied and pasted here from IntelliJ IDEA console. that's probably a decoding issue which doesn't allow to digest that correctly

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen Hello ! That's what is actually printed

Comment: Sounds very much like an encoding mismatch.   Based on personal experiences I would strongly suggest you reconsider having characters outside 7-bit ascii in your Windows username (and therefore home folder).  It is possible to rename your home folder if you have local administrator rights - I do not know if AD can do it.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen how to rename the home folder ? I have admin rights! But I cannot see the option "Rename" when right mouse clicking the folder in Windows Explorer..

Comment: The presence of `org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.LogSetup.initLoggers` in the stack trace leads me to suspect that the problem lies with how the program was invoked; specifically, it appears the log file location is not interpreted with the correct charset, which is why the Cyrillic characters are replaced with question marks.  Are you able to see the full command line used to execute the program?

Comment: @VGR Yes! I’m able to see the full java command and flags used to execute the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the related bug in IntelliJ IDEA bug tracker:

[Abnormal build process termination when OS user name contains non-Latin characters](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-243583/abnormal-build-process-termination-when-OS-user-name-contains-no)

Feel free to watch it in order to be notified once it has updates. See [this article](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241135) if you are not familiar with YouTrack.

As a workaround please consider installing IDE to a path with all the ascii characters or rename the OS user to have all the ascii letters. Sorry for the inconvenience.